# Why does the magnetic force exerted by two charged particles on each other do no work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, work

An electron and a proton are moving under the influence of mutual
forces. In calculating the change in the kinetic energy of the system
during motion, one ignores the magnetic force of one on another.
Why is it so?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. See: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73945/

Comment: Not really helpful to mark as a duplicate to a question that has no accepted answer and is also marked as a duplicate. This is a better link - though the answer to this question is in the question itself - the magnetic part of the Lorentz force is always perpendicular to velocity and so ${\bf F} \cdot {\bf v}$ will always be zero. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16326/

Comment: We actually **do** take into account the mutual magnetic forces. Co-incidentally, it is an example where  newton's third law does not hold.

Comment: @RobJeffries Your justification that F.v=0 implies no magnetic force acts is an incorrect one. In that case, during uniform circular motion the force acting is zero simply because the force and velocity are mutually perpendicular.(?)

Comment: @PhysicistByLogic Get a grip and read what *I* wrote. It wasn't what you say. The force is always perpendicular to the velocity. No *work* is done.

Comment: As pointed out by Rob, no *work* is done. However, it does not mean that the force can be **ignored** altogether. It may still affect the particle's trajectory. (in the same way the gravitational force on a planet in circular orbit around a star does no *work*,  but makes the planet follow a circular orbit).

Comment: @RobJeffries Pardon me for any misunderstanding, I didn't mean to offend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric and magnetic forces are defined via the [Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) on a charged particle

$$\vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$$

The magnetic force comes from the second term which defines it to be perpendicular to the velocity and therefore displacement $\vec {dr}$; so it doesn't do any work.