# magnetic field doing work on a wire

Tags: magnetostatics

I am a tutor and during a session today, a thought occurred to me. I've long been told (and been telling) that magnetic fields do no work, but it's pretty easy to imagine a situation in which a magnetic field DOES do work. If two wires have parallel currents traveling through them, with one wire situated above the other, the magnetic force would lift up the lower wire.

This would be basically the definition of work.

Why doesn't this negate the statement that magnetic forces do no work?

Comment: [Required reading](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67832/9887)

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic fields do no work on unconstrained charged particles. This comes from the Lorentz force law:
$$F = q\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$$
\begin{align}
dW &= \vec{F}\cdot{}d\vec{x} \\
 &= (q\vec{v} \times \vec{B})\cdot{}d\vec{x} \\
 &= (q\vec{v} \times \vec{B})\cdot{}\vec{v}\,dt \\
 &= 0
\end{align}
(The last step is due to $(\vec{x} \times \vec{y})\cdot\vec{x} = 0$ for any vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$.)

It is certainly possible for magnetic fields to do work on other things:

- Current-carrying wires: where the charged particles are confined to the wire, so their velocity is not always parallel to the force. See railguns for a dramatic example of magnetic fields doing work.
- Other magnets (namely, dipoles), whether through attraction/repulsion (if the field has a gradient) or purely torque (if the field is uniform)

Answer (score 0):

It is supprising how many people confuse work done   with energy. A static magnetic field contains no energy -and it is why  magnet only  based examples of  perpectual motion machines do not work . Magnetism is a force only, and work is done when a mass is moved a distance by that force. Clearly  the magnetic force is known to move  objects within its field of influence,and is capable of doing work as you  describe. Some might be convinced  that because work is done then energy  must be  available, however the only energy present is that which was first applied (eg  the power x time for which the parrallel conductors carrying  current) or  the energy required to place an object into the field of influence in the first place. The energy is either returned ( ideally) or converted into mechanical movement ( as per an electric motor). Static magnetic fields are not a source of energy.