# If is work done by magnetic field is 0 then why does 2 magnets attract when kept together?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, work

If 2 magnets are kept close to each other they attract then shouldn't it be considered as work done by magnetic field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Magnets be used to pick up pieces of metal when the force from a magnetic field does no work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67826/)

Comment: A magnet attracts or repels another magnet, doing  work. A magnet deflects a moving charged particle sideways, changing its direction but not its speed, and so doing no work.