# Deriving force acting on magnetic dipoles using the Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I was always taught that classically all electromagnetic phenomena are encapsulated in the Maxwell equations and the Lorentz force formula for point charges:
$$ \vec{F} = q\left(\vec{E}+\vec{v} \times \vec{B}\right)$$
but according to this equation the magnetic field doesn't do any work. So I have two seeming contradictions in mind that I can't explain:

1. I don't see how this formula can explain the energy a magnetic dipole has in a magnetic field:
   $$U=-\mathbf{m} \cdot \mathbf{B}$$
   According to the formula there should in no way be a generating potential for any magnetic force. And furthermore that dipole energy formula implies that the magnetic field can in fact accelerate and do work, no?
2. Also a phenomena that everyone observes with their own eyes: When you bring two permanent magnets together at some point they will snap together, accelerating and acquiring kinetic energy in the process. This is again seemingly the magnetic field doing work which isn't allowed by the Lorentz force.

How does one resolve all this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can magnets be used to pick up pieces of metal when the force from a magnetic field does no work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67826/how-can-magnets-be-used-to-pick-up-pieces-of-metal-when-the-force-from-a-magneti)

Comment: @SuperCiocia Almost! So the magnetic field doesn't do any work in itself but rather makes the electric field do work because it's constrained by some boundary condition. But that still doesn't explain how one comes up with the Potential formula for magnetic dipoles.

Comment: No, a uniform magnetic field does no work on a moving point charge. Not everything is a point charge and hence described by the Lorentz force. Also, the magnetic dipole formula is about a *torque*, which does indeed work.

Comment: @SuperCiocia I don't agree. You can build everything up from point charges if you allow functionals and integrals and since everything is linear whatever applies to point charges should also apply to every other sort of current.