# How understand the stored energy due to magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, potential-energy, classical-electrodynamics

I'm confusing because in this book[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBu9b.png) introduces the magnetic energy as mechanical work done by forced magnetic, but if magnetic force doesn't  work, besides do who done work?

[image]

Teruo Matsushita - Electricity and Magnetism New Formulation by Introduction of Superconductivity.

Preface's book says this

> Usually students learn about static magnetic energy after they study electromagnetic induction. One of the appreciable advantages of using a superconductor is
>   the direct derivation of magnetic energy as mechanical work done by magnetic
>   force, similar to the electric energy resulting from the electric force. This is because
>   the magnetic flux is conserved in a superconducting circuit disconnected from any
>   electric sources. As a result, the electromagnetic induction can be predicted for a
>   usual electric circuit using the relationship between the energy and magnetic force.
>   In electromagnetism the magnetic moment of a magnet caused by spins and
>   orbital motions of electrons is described using a virtual magnetizing current.
>   However, the magnetic moment of a superconductor comes from a real current
>   flowing in it. Hence, the introduction of the superconductor is also beneficial with
>   regard to persuasion of the appropriateness of the virtual magnetizing current.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the mechanism by which magnetic fields do work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89398/)

Comment: Other duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89398/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67826/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114627/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22530/

Comment: Also, for future posts, [please do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.