# The force on an infinite line of charge perpendicular to a on a rod of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics, electric-fields

Essentially the question is to calculate the force exerted by a charged rod perpendicular to an infinite line of charge: $\vec{F}_{\text{rod}\rightarrow \text{line}} =\dots$

My question is it okay to just find $\vec{F}_{\text{line}\rightarrow \text{rod}} =\dots$, basically calculating the force 'the opposite way', since this seems easier to do?

Answer (score 1):

Newton's 3rd law is fine to use in electrostatics.

Do be aware that [in certain situations, the third law is much more subtle;](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43283/29216) The momentum of the field itself sometimes needs to be taken into account