Lorentz force doubts
We know that Lorentz force on a test charge particle moving through a magnetic field is given by $$F=q_\text{test}\cdot(V_\text{test} \cdot B_\text{source/externalfield} \cdot \sin\theta)$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between velocity of the charged particle and the external magnetic field $B$. But we also know that the moving test charge produces its own magnetic field, will this reduce the net force on the test charge by the external magnetic field? If so, what would be the formula?

Test charges can’t exert force on themselves. You should be thinking about what the net EM field at the test charge is after accounting for its own EM field.

Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/459674/25301, possibly others

'Test charges can’t exert force on themselves.' If only it were so easy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Lorentz_force and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization.

@my2cts I doubt that that is of immediate concern to the asker. At the very least the AL force has to still conserve total energy…

This question is similar to: Force felt by a moving charge due to its own magnetic field?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@controlgroup It is of everyone's concern that we do not oversimplify physics here.

It’s also pointless to try and explain renormalized self-interaction forces to someone clearly at a more-basic physics level (nothing wrong with that!) and who didn’t directly ask about those forces.

@controlgroup Oversimplifications such as yours are in no one's interest.

Sure, but the AL force is proportional to $\mu_0$ (small in SI) and also written out in the non-simplified form as a very complicated expression of powers of the Lorentz factor and derivatives of acceleration. Sure, you could explain that, and that wouldn’t be an oversimplification and it would answer the question (which would probably deserve an upvote). But if what’s being asked is “does the charge’s own magnetic field affect the Lorentz force on it” and not “how does the self-interaction through the EM field generate a secondary recoil force”, a simpler explanation might be merited.

Thanks a lot for helping me out here , im just a high school student . thanks for your help
