# Does classical electrodynamics break momentum conservation in some cases?

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, conservation-laws, classical-electrodynamics

Particularly in the case of non divergence free currents does the Lorenz force break newton's 3rd law?

This question is purely theoretical, it's only about what the theory says. So no experimental arguments.

Of course em fields can carry energy_momentum and if energy or momentum go in the fields that's not breaking conservation laws.

I am asking weather there are theoretical examples with an assumption of a non divergence free current density where when accounting the whole system momentum is not conserved in general electrodynamics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apparent Violation of Newton's $3^{\text{rd}}$ Law and the Conservation of Momentum (and Angular Momentum) For a Pair of Charged Particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114466/)

Comment: and this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136835/

Comment: Take a look at my answer in the link given by @SpiralRain. It is the correct one although it has rating - 1.

Comment: Your question is not sufficient ntly precise. Show an example for which you think that momentum is not conserved.