# Confusion regarding Magnetic field expression due to a small current element (Newton's Third law seems invalid)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, conservation-laws

Biot Savart Law is given as :
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=\oint\limits_{\textrm{around}}^{\textrm{wire}}\dfrac{I\,\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell'}\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}\right)}{\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \vert^{3}}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
The book that I'm following says that if we take 
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=\dfrac{I\,\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell'}\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}\right)}{\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \vert^{3}}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
for a current element $\,I\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell'}\,$,
then this will not be a correct assumption since the force exerted by $\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{B}\,$ on a charge $\,q\,$ at position $\,\mathbf{r}\,$ moving with velocity $\,\mathbf{V}\,$ is

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{F}=\dfrac{Iq\mathbf{V}}{c}\boldsymbol{\times}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell'}\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}\right)}{\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \vert^{3}}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}

and since "this force violates Newton's Third Law. It is not directed along the line joining the current element with the charge."
I don't get this quoted line. How is Newton's Third law acting here?

I can give you the exact texts of the book.[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5xLxIcmK_z1TTQzcHFxdklmYms)

---

**Here is a general outline of the solution which I thought for the question**

1.See that Newton's third law is connected to the conservation of momentum principle.
2.Now evaluate the $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ fields and hence $\mathbf F_B$ and $\mathbf F_E$ by [the corresponding laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law#Point_charge_at_constant_velocity).
3.See that net force is not conserved which implies momentum should not be conserved.
4. Hence we cannot use the expression of '$d \mathbf B$' for the line element

Comment: Where does Newton's third law mention that all forces that exist must be central forces?

Comment: At first take a look therein : [Apparent violation of Newton's 3rd law and the conservation of angular momentum for a pair of charged particles interacting magnetically](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114466/).

Comment: In _"Classical Electrodynamics"_, J.D.Jackson, 3rd Ed., $\S$ 5.2 Biot and Savart Law :   
A word of caution about (5.4)( here 02). .... Equation (5.4)(here 02) **has meaning only as one element of a sum over a continuous set**, the sum representing
the magnetic induction of a current loop or circuit. Obviously the continuity equation (5.3) ($\;\boldsymbol{\nabla}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{J}=0$) is not satisfied for the current element $\,I\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell'}\,$ standing alone-the current comes from nowhere and disappears after traversing the length $\,\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell'}$ !

Comment: My previous comment (Jackson)  is an extra information, not an answer  about  Newton's Third law violation. But I think that Emilio Pisanty answer  (in the link given above) is a  satisfactory explanation of this apparent violation.

Comment: See also : [Violation of Newton's 3rd law and momentum conservation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43269/).

Comment: Hi Icchyamoy. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.