# Why doesn't a uniformly moving particle radiate?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

When considering a uniformly moving charged particle, we have the following fields:

$$\vec E = \frac{q(1-\beta^2)}{4\pi\epsilon R_a}\vec R$$
$$\vec B = \frac{1}{c^2}\vec u \times \vec E$$

With $\vec u$ the velocity of the particle.

The Poynting-Vector is $\vec S = \vec E \times \vec H$ which isn't $0$ since the 2 fields are perpendicular, so why do we say that there's no radiation here if there is a non-zero amount of energy being radiated?

Comment: Related:  [Does a nonzero Poynting vector mean that there is propagation of energy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17141/9887)

Comment: The fields are tied to the particle,  there is propagation in the sense that the fields follow the particle ; to have   radiation  the fields should be propagating independently of a charge source, by the definition of radiation.

Comment: I understand that, but that doesn't explain the behaviour of the Poynting-vector or am I not seeing it?

Comment: Well, technically any wave is EM radiation. Usually though, when talking about the Poynting vector people use it to determine the power being transmitted in the wave $P = \frac{1}{2} \lvert \vec P \rvert $. Since power is energy per unit time, I guess you could multiply it by the transmission length  (in seconds) to get the total energy $U_{total} = P t_{transmission}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Look at the Poynting-vector associated with an electric charge Q and a bar magnet, and then consider $\int\int {\bf E}\times {\bf B} . d{\bf S}$ around a *closed* surface.