# Momentum of capacitor in a uniform magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, momentum

We are observing ideal, charged, parallel plate capacitor placed in uniform magnetic field parallel to plates. Whole system is at rest and isolated (we have forces that hold plates separated, but net force is zero) and, according to **"Center of energy theorem"**, it must contains zero total momentum. System has non-zero momentum stored in electromagnetic field so we must have some **"hidden" momentum** so the total momentum would be zero? Where is it "hiding"?

Comment: Possibly related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7218/

Comment: There is nothing paradoxical about Poynting vector cause divS=0 and energy doesnt flow. Question is more about correct application of "Center of energy theorem". Total momentum should be zero? 
P.S. I have already seen both of link posted in above two comments and they are not solution of this problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I wanted to say that conservation of energy is satisfied, not that energy doesnt flow.

Comment: @Mihailo_Serbia, the Griffith's paper link seems to directly address your question:  "*What about a capacitor in the magnetic field of a solenoid?
In this case the hidden momentum is located in the solenoid (that is where the moving charges are), and the electric field responsible for the variation in $\gamma$ must be the exterior fringing field of the capacitor.*"  Stating that there is a uniform magnetic field and then not looking for momentum stored in the *source* of that field may be the problem here.  http://www.ate.uni-duisburg-essen.de/data/postgraduate_lecture/AJP_2009_Griffiths.pdf

Comment: Thank you! Ill study it carefully. At the beginning I refused to pay attention on fringing fields and blindly calculated momentum using Poynting theorem. It is so cool that problem make us to watch source of field.

Comment: P.S. It is possible to have non-zero mechanical momentum of some system and not having motion of center of mass of that system? (I know it is related to link posted by BowlofRed, but discussion on that link doesnt give a straight answer)